# Knowing $A, P$, find the diagonal matrix $D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, diagonalization

Say we have a matrix $A$ which is Diagonalizable, and $P$ which can be used in diagonalizing $A$. We are tasked to find the diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A = PDP^{-1}$

Since we know $A,P$, and it is given that $P$ can be used in diagonalizing $A$ why can't we just do $P^{-1}AP = D$?

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
-3&-4\\
-9&-3\\
\end{pmatrix}, P = \begin{pmatrix}
2&-2\\
3&3\\
\end{pmatrix}, P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
3&2\\
-3&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Multiplying $P^{-1}AP$ yields  $\begin{pmatrix}
-108&0\\
0&36\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Yet, $D$ is actually $\begin{pmatrix}
-9&0\\
0&3\\
\end{pmatrix}$

May someone explain to me why, if we know $A,P,P^{-1}$ and we use legitimate operations to compute $D$, we still don't get $D$? I mean I get a form of $D$ (aka. row equivalent, if I were to divide by $12$, but I don't know this just doing the calculation itself)..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the wrong result because your inverse is incorrect. You are forgetting to divide by the determinant of $P$.

Comment: Ahhh right, forgot that it's not simply  $(\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix})^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
d&-b\\
-c&a\\
\end{pmatrix}$! Thanks!